# Connectionless named pipes on windows

Tags: c++, c

What I want to do is create a named pipe server that routes messages between connected peers. On Windows it seems that you first have to create a pipe and then connect it to a client and then you read from the connected client pipe to get the message you want and then that handle is bound to that client and you have to create a new named pipe. Is there no way to easily multiplex all the clients into one handle so I don't have to read from each client separately? To write to the clients from the server you obviously have to use the clients’ handle. Maybe the server can close the connection every time it has processed a request but that seems a bit unnecessarily wasteful. I would rather avoid implementing my own named pipes with shared memory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"you first have to create a pipe and then connect it to a client"

Not exactly. The server process creates the pipe, but the client connects itself. Also, the client can try to connect and block if the server hasn't yet created the pipe.

"you read from the connected client pipe to get the message you want and then that handle is bound to that client". True. Doesn't stop you from immediately waiting for the next client.

"Is there no way to easily multiplex all the clients into one handle?". No, that would defeat the point of the `HANDLE`. That's the bit you need to demultiplex the clients.

What you seem to miss is that you can set the number of pipe instances to `PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES`, and read all of them using a shared [`LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE` callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/nc-minwinbase-lpoverlapped_completion_routine). The callback will tell you which `HANDLE` and thus which pipe has data available.

Comment: In order to read from all of them I have to do WaitMultipleObjectsEx right? That has a max-limit of 64 which is not a whole lot. Am I missing something?

Comment: @christianO: `SleepEx` would be enough, which takes 0 handles. The completion routine just needs an alertable thread to run on. It will get the OVERLAPPED structure, and that contains the exact HANDLE.